# $\omega$ is $1$-form on $S^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $h: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ be $h(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$. How do I show that if $\omega$ is any $1$-form on $S^1$, then$$\int_{S^1} \omega = \int_0^{2\pi} h^*\omega?$$

Comment: This is just a change of coordinates. Please check the definition of pullback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the integral of a $1$-form is defined. One then checks it is independent of the parametrization used.